# gettimeofday() not using vDSO?

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, vdso

I strace'd a java process that was triggering a lot of kernel time to see what syscalls were being used, and was surprised to see that `gettimeofday()` and `clock_gettime()` dominated (I suspect it's due to logging), which is strange considering that `man vdso` states:

When tracing systems calls with **strace**(1), symbols (system calls) that are exported by the vDSO will not appear in the trace output.

How come these system calls are happening? Is there a way to avoid them?

The machine is running Ubuntu 16.04.1 on EC2.

To make things easier, I created a minimal test program in C (`testgtod.c`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void main(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        /* glibc wrapped, shouldn't actually syscall */
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    }
}
```

I then compiled and ran the program under strace: `gcc testgtod.c -o testgtod && sudo strace ./testgtod`

The output included a thousand calls to gettimeofday(), despite my expectation.

Things I tested to make sure I'm not seeing things:

1. Made sure the binary is a 64-bit elf using `file`
2. `ldd ./testgtod` to make sure vDSO is active:

   **linux-vdso.so.1** =>  (0x00007ffcee25d000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6f6e161000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559ed71f3000)
3. `getauxval(AT_SYSINFO_EHDR) != NULL`
4. Replaced `gettimeofday(&tv, NULL)` calls with `syscall(SYS_gettimeofday, &tv, NULL)`, increased number of calls to 10 million, ran under `time` - runtime behavior was the same in both cases: `./testgtod  0.16s user 0.83s system 99% cpu 0.998 total`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is related to this being a VM running on Xen, specifically, the Xen clocksource does not yet allow for vDSO access to the clock:

```
ubuntu@machine:~% cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/*/current_clocksource
xen
```

Then, I changed the clocksource to `tsc`:

```
ubuntu@machine:~% sudo sh -c "echo tsc >/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource"
```

<s>**NOTE:** it isn't recommended to move to the `tsc` clocksource on production machines since it may cause backwards drift for the clock.</s>

See https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/08/system-calls-are-much-slower-on-ec2/ for a detailed write-up on the interaction between vDSO and the clocksource.

**NOTE 2**: it seems `tsc` support in Xen has improved with version 4.0 and with improved CPU support in Sandy Bridge+ platforms. Modern EC2 machines should be okay with `tsc`. Check Xen version using `dmesg | grep "Xen version"`. Amazon recommended the `tsc` clocksource already in re:Invent 2015 (https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/cmp402-amazon-ec2-instances-deep-dive). I'm not yet running to production with this, but the situation doesn't seem as bad as implied by packagecloud.

Additional reading:
[Why `rdtsc` interacts poorly with VMs](http://oliveryang.net/2015/09/pitfalls-of-TSC-usage/)
[Xen's 4.0 rdtsc changes](http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.2-testing/misc/tscmode.txt)
[Linux kernel timekeeping documentation, discussing the pitfalls of the TSC](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.4/Documentation/virtual/kvm/timekeeping.txt)